# How do I make auto git pull request on my laptop that hosts my Discord bot?

Tags: git, github, discord.js

I have a laptop that I use to host my Discord bot, how would I make it when I publish changes to the repo my laptop automatically makes a pull request?

btw the laptop is running Windows 10

Comment: How soon after changes are published does the laptop need to update? The easiest way to do this may be to use a scheduled task which runs a "git pull" periodically.

Comment: Also, the question is a bit confusing, as it mentions "pull request", but I think you simply mean "git pull", which is not the same thing.